# Query for getting rows with dates between certian range(stored as string in form of dd-mm-yyyy)

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have date stored in the form of TEXT in sqllite database. The format is "dd-mm-yyyy". I am making a query to select rows having dates in between two given dates. When I query the database with query dates belonging to the same month, I am getting the results. But, when the date range belong to different month, it returns no rows. For eg:

The problem arises when the dates are something like : 29-03-2013 to 05-04-2013. It returns rows successfully when the dates are between: 02-04-2013 and 05-04-2013. There are rows with entries made on all the dates.

Following are the ways I have tried:

```
// MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_DATE stores column name which is 'date'
// startdate and end date are string in form of mm-dd-yyyy
// MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAMES contain table name string
// MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MOOD_LEVEL is another column that I wish to get in return
```

I have tried using the BETWEEN clause and the <= and >=, but no effect to the output. Here is how:

```
// Method 1:
String selection = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_DATE + " BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+ enddate+"' "; 
// Method 2:
String selection = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_DATE + " >= '"+startdate+"' AND "+MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE_DATE+" <= '"+ enddate+"' ";

String []colum = {MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_MOOD_LEVEL};
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAMES, colum, selection, null, null, null, null);
```

When I use

```
cursor.getCount()
```

to see the number of rows returned, it gives 0. Though there are entries existing in between those dates.

Is their some basic comparison issue that I am missing? I tried looking at some previous questions but didn't work out. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For string comparisons to work correctly, you must use a format where the most significant field comes first, i.e., `yyyy-mm-dd`. (This also is the only supported format for SQLite's [built-in date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).)

Answer (score 1):

Before the query , i would like to highlight the **correct Date format** that is

> yyyy-MM-dd

Make sure to save your date in this format.then further the query is following :

```
 Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, COL_GAME_DATE + " BETWEEN ? AND ?", new String[]{
                        startDate, endDate},
                null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you rather fix your database first. Dates should be stored in DATE type, just because of simplicity of further use.

Comment: SQLite [does not have a DATE type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: That's correct, there's no dedicated type but I (imprecisely) meant putting date into column type that know how to deal with it, which meant TEXT with properly formatted date.